# Editable Table in javafx2

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I created table with editable cell at run time using javafx2. The table cell is edited but not updated while pressing enter key, and also table class  set method showing error at the location **tab_bankname.set(tab_bankname);** in bankmodal.java, error message

> The method set(String) is undefined for the type String

**Table Class Name : bankmodal.java**

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class bankmodal {

    public final StringProperty tab_bankname;
    public final StringProperty tab_bankaccno;
    public final StringProperty tab_accname;
    public final StringProperty tab_uniqueno;
    public final StringProperty  tab_address;
    public final StringProperty  tab_accounttype;
    public final StringProperty  tab_ifsc;
    public final StringProperty  tab_micr;

    public  bankmodal(String tab_uniqueno,String tab_accname,String tab_bankaccno,
                String tab_address,String tab_accounttype,String tab_ifsc,String tab_micr,String tab_bankname)
    {

        this.tab_bankaccno = new SimpleStringProperty(tab_bankaccno);
        this.tab_address = new SimpleStringProperty(tab_address);
        this.tab_accounttype = new SimpleStringProperty(tab_accounttype);
        this.tab_ifsc = new SimpleStringProperty(tab_ifsc);
        this.tab_accname = new SimpleStringProperty(tab_accname);
        this.tab_uniqueno = new SimpleStringProperty(tab_uniqueno);
        this.tab_micr = new SimpleStringProperty(tab_micr);
        this.tab_bankname = new SimpleStringProperty(tab_bankname);
    }


    public String getTab_bankname() {
        return tab_bankname.get();
    }


    public void setTab_bankname(String tab_bankname) {
        tab_bankname.set(tab_bankname);
    }


    public String getTab_bankaccno() {
        return tab_bankaccno.get();
    }


    public void setTab_bankaccno(String tab_bankaccno) {
        tab_bankaccno.set(getTab_bankaccno());
    }


    public String getTab_accname() {
        return tab_accname.get();
    }


    public void setTab_accname(String tab_accname) {
        tab_accname.set(tab_accname);
    }


    public String getTab_uniqueno() {
        return tab_uniqueno.get();
    }


    public void setTab_uniqueno(String tab_uniqueno) {
        tab_uniqueno.set(tab_uniqueno);
    }


    public String getTab_address() {
        return tab_address.get();
    }


    public void setTab_address(String tab_address) {
        tab_address.set(tab_address);
    }


    public String getTab_accounttype() {
        return tab_accounttype.get();
    }


    public void setTab_accounttype(String tab_accounttype) {
        tab_accounttype.set(tab_accounttype);
    }


    public String getTab_ifsc() {
        return tab_ifsc.get();
    }


    public void setTab_ifsc(String tab_ifsc) {
        tab_ifsc.set(tab_ifsc);
    }


    public String getTab_micr() {
        return tab_micr.get();
    }


    public void setTab_micr(String tab_micr) {
        tab_micr.set(tab_micr);
    }
}
```

**Controller Class Name : Bank.java**

```
public void fetchData(){
    bankDetails.setEditable(true);
    try{
        bank = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        ps = con.prepareStatement("select clientid,clientname,accountnumber,bankaddress,accounttype,ifsccode,branchname,bankname from bank");
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            bank.add(new bankmodal(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4), rs.getString(5),rs.getString(6),rs.getString(7),rs.getString(8)));

        }

        tab_uniqueno.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("tab_uniqueno"));

        tab_accname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("tab_accname"));
        tab_accname.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<bankmodal>forTableColumn());
        tab_accname.setOnEditCommit(
            new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<bankmodal, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(CellEditEvent<bankmodal, String> t) {
                    ((bankmodal) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                        ).setTab_accname(t.getNewValue());
                }
            }
        );
        tab_bankaccno.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("tab_bankaccno"));
        tab_bankaccno.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<bankmodal>forTableColumn());
        tab_bankaccno.setOnEditCommit(
            new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<bankmodal, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(CellEditEvent<bankmodal, String> t) {
                    ((bankmodal) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                        ).setTab_bankaccno(t.getNewValue());
                }
            }
        );
        tab_address.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("tab_address"));
        tab_address.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<bankmodal>forTableColumn());
        tab_address.setOnEditCommit(
            new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<bankmodal, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(CellEditEvent<bankmodal, String> t) {
                    ((bankmodal) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                        ).setTab_address(t.getNewValue());
                }
            }
        );
        tab_accounttype.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("tab_accounttype"));
        tab_accounttype.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<bankmodal>forTableColumn());
        tab_accounttype.setOnEditCommit(
            new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<bankmodal, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(CellEditEvent<bankmodal, String> t) {
                    ((bankmodal) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                        ).setTab_accounttype(t.getNewValue());
                }
            }
        );
        tab_ifsc.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("tab_ifsc"));
        tab_ifsc.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<bankmodal>forTableColumn());
        tab_ifsc.setOnEditCommit(
            new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<bankmodal, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(CellEditEvent<bankmodal, String> t) {
                    ((bankmodal) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                        ).setTab_ifsc(t.getNewValue());
                }
            }
        );
        tab_micr.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("tab_micr"));
        tab_micr.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<bankmodal>forTableColumn());
        tab_micr.setOnEditCommit(
            new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<bankmodal, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(CellEditEvent<bankmodal, String> t) {
                    ((bankmodal) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                        ).setTab_micr(t.getNewValue());
                }
            }
        );
        tab_bankname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("tab_bankname"));
        tab_bankname.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<bankmodal>forTableColumn());
        tab_bankname.setOnEditCommit(
            new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<bankmodal, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(CellEditEvent<bankmodal, String> t) {
                    ((bankmodal) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                        ).setTab_bankname(t.getNewValue());
                }
            }
        );

        bankDetails.setItems(null);

        bankDetails.setItems(bank);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Main Class Name : Main.java

Comment: You have getters and setters for every property, so why not add the property getters like `tab_banknameProperty` and save yourself the trouble of adding the `onEditCommit` handlers?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this method:

```
public void setTab_bankname(String tab_bankname) {
    tab_bankname.set(tab_bankname);
}
```

Here, `tab_bankname` can be either your parameter `String tab_bankname` or your member field `public final StringProperty tab_bankname`, it is unclear what you are referencing.

You got the following error **runtime**:

> The method set(String) is undefined for the type String

because in runtime `tab_bankname` has a reference to the parameter, which is a `String` which does not has a method `set(String)`.

Normally your IDE shall give you the same error in compile time to avoid runtime exception.

### To avoid this confusion:

**First solution: Use "this" (and update all of your getters with this)**

This ensures that `this.tab_bankname` is a `StringProperty`

```
public void setTab_bankname(String tab_bankname) {
    this.tab_bankname.set(tab_bankname);
}
```

**Second solution: Do not use the same name in the parameter as any of your members**

```
public void setTab_bankname(String _bankName) {
    tab_bankname.set(_bankName);
}
```

You could also quickly read through the [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html) to avoid such confusions in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your help.Mr DVarga